# How to build a library .dll with MinGW?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, mingw

I try to build a iec61850.dll library file with cmake but the operation don't generate any file in the debug folder. You can find the entire library folder in
http://libiec61850.com/libiec61850/downloads/ .
And also the way way to build in http://libiec61850.com/libiec61850/documentation/building-the-library/

I really need your help i'm a beginner in programming.

Comment: Please post the full error log, and the command line you have tried using.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c#] as well as [tag:c++]? And being new to programming is no sufficient excuse to not take the [tour]. Visiting the [help] is also highly recommended.

Comment: command line i have tried is: cmake -G "Visual Studio 11"  in the build directory .sorry i tagged c# because the library i tried to build, i'll use it in c# app

Comment: If the library uses C++ there is no chance in the world it'll work with C#. Are you sure you want to use MinGW? It doesn't seem like you do (i.e. you use the "Visual Studio 11" CMake generator, and not e.g. the "MinGW Makefiles" generator).

Comment: i included the iec61850 library for .Net in my project but the execution depends on Iec61850.dll that i read in documentation file that i should place in win32.                                                                                            i get this exceptions " An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotfoundE‌​xception' occurred in iec61850dotnet.dll" Additional information: unable to load DLL 'IEC61850' :The specified module could not be found.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007e )

Comment: the problem is that i don't know how to build iec61850.dll